# Migrating local Wordpress site to Openshift

Tags: deployment, migration

I started developing on Wordpress and I have a simple website on my computer. I followed [this article](http://www.codedrops.in/wordpress-tutorial/openshift-wordpress-install-source/) to transfer all the WP structure to Openshift.

On my local website I applied themes, create widgets, add pictures. Created the about page, created an image gallery, the contact and the home page. I committed my changes and pushed them to Openshift. I backed up my local database and then restored on Openshift.

Then, I checked my website on Openshift and I don't see all the changes that appear on my local website. Why is this happening? Does it mean that I need to go to the admin panel and start making those changes again in the live site?

I thought that by just git pushing everything it was goign to be transferred to the live website. Is there any way to migrate my local website to Openshift?

Comment: Do you mean code changes or content changes?